# access an external windows forms application and read its content

Tags: windows, forms, external-application

I'm trying to produce an application which scans through another application and finds telephone numbers that it shows on its forms. I don't know beforehand which external application it will be, but I do know that it will be a windows forms application.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: You want to read some random form that displays a grid or list with list of phone numbers??

Comment: Not exactly. The idea is that this external application may display phone numbers somewhere on the page, as a description of a customer or such. If this is the case, I want to scan for that number in the application and do something with it in my app. So I don't know beforehand in what format or location it will be displayed.